# Can't create a+r file

Tags: files, permissions

Using Debian I am unable to create files that by default has read permission for all users.

For example:

```
# umask
0002
# touch test
# ls -l test
-rw-rw----+ 1 user user 0 Jun 25 18:18 test
```

Is there any specific restriction on creating readable files?

Comment: the `+` at the file perm. output is the giveaway that *ACL* is overriding the permission settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your system use ACLs, so the file will have extended permission. Try:

```
getfacl test
```

to see exactly file permission.

Comment: There is that string here `default:other::---`. I it relative to my question? I tested current directory.

Comment: Well, I tried `setfacl -m "default:other:r--"`, and it worked. Thanks for the hint.